# find open/close tag and replace?

Tags: regex

I have string:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <object width="500" height="500" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="http://www.abc.com/m/l5J16d65wOpT" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
</object> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Now, i want to add `<div class="player"></div>` around object tag, it's will become:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <div class="player"><object width="500" height="500" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="http://www.abc.com/m/l5J16d65wOpT" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
</object></div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want? I really don't get it.

Comment: Ok, feel free to add whatever you want.  You have our approval.

Comment: so hard to post new topic T_T

Comment: Well you have to describe your problem as exactly as possible to get asap an answer.

Answer (score 1):

a [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) might be useful here :)

```
$result = preg_replace('|(<object.*</object>)|sui', '<div class="player">$1</div>', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace it like this, then just use the normal `str_replace`

```
//PHP
$myString = str_replace("<object>", "<div class=\"player\"><object>", $originalString);
$myString = str_replace("</object>", "</object></div>", $originalString);
```